# Python: Plotting 2 dimensional function of two variables

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the function:

```
def g(R, r):
    return (np.sqrt(2.0 * (R + r) / (r * R)) - (1 + np.sqrt(R)) / np.sqrt(R) -
            np.sqrt(2.0 / (r * (1 + r))) * (1 - r) -
            (1.0 / np.sqrt(R) - np.sqrt(2.0) * (1 - R) / np.sqrt(R * (1 + R))
             - 1))
```

The function is defined by setting `delta v_B = delta v_H` where `delta v_B` is

```
np.sqrt(2.0 * (R + r) / (r * R)) - (1 + np.sqrt(R)) / np.sqrt(R) -
                np.sqrt(2.0 / (r * (1 + r))) * (1 - r)
```

and `delta v_H` is

```
1.0 / np.sqrt(R) - np.sqrt(2.0) * (1 - R) / np.sqrt(R * (1 + R)) - 1
```

Therefore, I wrote `g` as `delta v_b - delta v_H`.

Now this is my function and the code I am using below:

```
import pylab
import numby as np


def g(R, r):
    return (np.sqrt(2.0 * (R + r) / (r * R)) - (1 + np.sqrt(R)) / np.sqrt(R) -
            np.sqrt(2.0 / (r * (1 + r))) * (1 - r) -
            (1.0 / np.sqrt(R) - np.sqrt(2.0) * (1 - R) / np.sqrt(R * (1 + R))
             - 1))


r = np.linspace(11.9, 16, 500000)
R = np.linspace(1, 20, 500000)

fig2 = pylab.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)
ax2.plot(R, g(R, r), 'r')
pylab.xlabel('$R_1 = \\frac{r_C}{r_A}$')
pylab.ylabel('$R_2 = \\frac{r_B}{r_A}$')
pylab.xlim((0, 25))
pylab.ylim((0, 100))                               

pylab.show()
```

The function should asymptote to infinity at about `11.94` and intersect the line `y = x` at around `15.58`

How can I make such a plot?  I am not familiar with how to do this, and I don't know how to plot such a function.

Is my definition improper for `g` as `g(R, r)`?  If so, how should it be defined if this isn't the case?

[image]

Comment: What is the mean of "the function should asymptote to infinity at about 11.94" I'm not understand, why one component only?. And, what is r,R, they are lengths?

Comment: @Pablo at 11.94 the function go up to positive infinity but not crossing that value only approaching it.  Little 'r' is supposed to be y axis values.  I will draw a poor picture to show you what I mean.

Comment: @Pablo I added my horrible drawing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is call Implicit function curve, you can use `contour` to draw it with argument `levels=[0]`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def g(R, r):
    return (np.sqrt(2.0 * (R + r) / (r * R)) - (1 + np.sqrt(R)) / np.sqrt(R) -
            np.sqrt(2.0 / (r * (1 + r))) * (1 - r) -
            (1.0 / np.sqrt(R) - np.sqrt(2.0) * (1 - R) / np.sqrt(R * (1 + R))
             - 1))

R, r = np.mgrid[1:30:200j, 1:100:200j]
Z = g(R,r)
plt.contour(R, r, Z, colors='k', levels=[0]) 
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: How can I clip the curved portion under `y=x`?